# keep Guard running inside a docker container

Tags: ruby, docker, guard

everyone.
Is there a way to keep [Guard](https://github.com/guard/guard) running inside a docker container?

At this point, I have tried many different things but all seems to fail.

Originally I was running it `bundle exec guard ....` but since now I need to manage the Docker container with Docker Cloud I cannot specify anymore -i as option to the run command so with that approach Guard closes right after booting.

```
11:03:18 - INFO - Guard is now watching at '/usr/app'
11:03:19 - INFO - Bye bye...
```

I tried to run Guard programmatically from a ruby file as such

```
...
guardfile = <<-EOF
  ...
EOF
Guard.start(guardfile_contents: guardfile)
```

with the same outcome.

I have also tried to use directly the [listen gem](https://github.com/guard/listen) but in this case the changes to files are not picked up.

Now, I'm out of options. Any suggestions?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

If you cannot specify the `-i` option anymore, you can still get the same effect by disabling interation inside the `Guardfile`:

https://github.com/guard/guard/wiki/Guardfile-DSL---Configuring-Guard#interactor

with: `interactor :off`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have however solved the issue by stop using Guard.